# Find history with a pattern in R

Tags: r, history

In Linux bash, I can use something like

```
history | egrep "df"
```

and it will list all instances of my history that have the pattern "df" in them.

I am trying to find a similar syntax for R software. I found something similar here ([history search backward in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916189/history-search-backward-in-r)), however, the suggestion in the first answer did not seem to work.

Based off that answer, I tried the following in R:

```
> history(pattern="df\\(")
> history(pattern="df(")
> history(pattern="df")
```

But got no history commands with pattern "df" outputted to console (or outputted to anywhere else I could see).

Thank you...

Comment: Just a quick tip. That you care about the history let's me suspect that your workflow is not optimal. It is recommended to write all commands in a script (preferably using an IDE, but Rgui lets you do that as well) and send them to R from there.

Comment: `history(pattern="df")` works fine for me on Linux (`?history` says that the history mechanism works different on Unix-alikes and Windows ..)

Comment: Something I recently stumbled upon: if you are using a mac and press `command + up` in the console in Rstudio, it will display your recent history in a scroll window. Probably not useful here, though.

Comment: Rstudio has a history pane with its own search window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This alternate version works for me:

```
grep("df", readLines(".Rhistory"), value=T)
```

The `history` version also did not work for me.  The docs mention that the history functions are somewhat implementation dependent.  For example, in Rstudio, `history()` returns nothing.

Also, you may need to run `savehistory()` before the grep because your console may buffer the history for a while before actually writing it to file.

Comment: Why does `grep('?', readLines('.Rhistory'), value = TRUE)` act weird?

Comment: Note that `?` is a character with special significance in a regular expression.  If you want to match a literal `?` you need to use "\\?" as the regular expression.

Comment: Or add `fixed=TRUE` as an argument